# WWW::Scripter as parent class causes weird error message

Tags: javascript, perl, www-mechanize

when I use [`WWW::Scripter`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Scripter) normally everything works fine:

```
use WWW::Scripter;
my $m = WWW::Scripter->new();
$m->use_plugin('JavaScript');
$m->get('http://some-site-with-java-script.com');
```

But when I try to subclass `WWW::Scripter` like so:

```
package MyScripter;

use parent qw(WWW::Scripter);

sub new {
  my ($class, @args) = @_;
  my $self = $class->SUPER::new(@args);
  return $self;
} 

package main;

my $m = MyScripter->new();
$m->use_plugin('JavaScript');
$m->get('http://some-site-with-java-script.com');
```

I get this strange error message:

```
Error: Can't locate object method "prop" via package "MyScripter" at /home/myuser/localperl/lib/site_perl/5.18.2/JE/LValue.pm line 91
```

What is going on?

```
WWW::Scripter::VERSION  => 0.030
JE::VERSION     => 0.060
```

Comment: I just looked at the [`WWW'Scripter` source](https://metacpan.org/source/LXP/WWW-Scripter-0.030/lib/WWW/Scripter.pm) trying to figure stuff out. My eyes, oh my eyes! I won't be going there again \*shudder\*. Considering these circumstances, I recommend using aggregation instead of inheritance.

Comment: How can a module advertise itself as inheriting everything from WWW::Mechanizer while at the same time making itself so hard to inherit from?

Comment: Is your code really as you have shown it? The `use MyScripter` line is wrong if you have really defined the `MyScripter` package in the same source file. It will either die because you have no `MyScripter.pm` in `@INC`, or it will incorrectly load a second copy of the module.

Comment: Actually I just put these two files together for convenience in order to make my point.

Comment: @waiferv: Ah, well it doesn't make your point as I just get `Can't locate MyScripter.pm in @INC`. It is as well to post your real code, or at least something that exhibits the same problem.

Comment: Edited. So run this. I just noticed that I get different error messages of the form Error: Can't locate object method "typeof" via package "MyScripter" at /home/myuser/localperl/lib/site_perl/5.18.2/JE/LValue.pm line 135
Error: Can't locate object method "to_boolean" via package "MyScripter" at /home/myuser/localperl/lib/site_perl/5.18.2/JE/LValue.pm line 135
Depending on what JavaScript website I open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guessed that the problem was dependent on the site being accessed, as I tried it with `http://www.bbc.co.uk/` with no problems at all (except that it doesn't like the JavaScript apearing in XHTML `CDATA` sections).

This is because of a broken inheritance hierarchy. I haven't found the exact problem, but I believe it is because of the way the `JavaScript` plugin works. It expects to be (insists on being) called in the context of a `WWW::Scripter` object, and has an explicit

```
use WWW::Scripter 0.022
```

at the start, which will load all the method definitions from the basic module instead of from your subclass.

There is all sorts of nasty stuff in there, such as using the Perl 4 package name separator, like `use LWP'UserAgent`, and literal path loads like

```
require "WWW/Scripter/Plugin/JavaScript/" . "$$self[benm].pm"
```

which could hardly be more anti-inheritance.

Without some more work it is hard to tell whether it's an easy fix or a rewrite, but to solve your problem I suggest using *roles* rather than inheritance, which allows the role model much more freedom in how it does its thing. It's described nicely in [perldoc perlootut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html#Roles) and you do a lot worse than experimenting with [`Role::Tiny`](http://search.cpan.org/~haarg/Role-Tiny-1.003002/lib/Role/Tiny.pm).

Comment: So could I create some sort of role wrapper for `WWW::Scripter` that I can use in my class?

Comment: @waiferv: Probably, yes. I can't say a lot without knowing much more about your application. `amon` suggested *aggregation*. If you think of your objects in terms of `ISA` (inheritance) `HASA` (aggregation) or `DOES` (role) then it should help a lot.